# zsh: command not found: ng

Tags: bash, npm, command, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have setup my angular project in bash terminal(default one). Command like

```
ng s
```

It worked fine.

Now I change my default terminal to zsh.
On running command

```
ng serve
```

throws error:

```
zsh: command not found: ng
```

> It work fine if I switch my new default-terminal(zsh) to bash; again to zsh.
> *I think zsh does not understand the packages installed in bash initially*

How to fix this command not found issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, on startup **bash** adds **ng** location to `PATH`, but **zsh** doesn't. You can check `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bashprofile` to see what is added to the `PATH` variable (all lines starting with `export...`), and copy these lines to `~/.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error "ng: command not found",
install the angular cli package globally by
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` and restart your terminal.

If the global installation of Angular fails, you might have to run the command prefixed with `sudo`.

get package version `ng version`.

Answer (score 0):

ng command auto autocomplete for angular added to your PATH, to fix this just try to remove it from...

[image]
for me this command added to  ~/.zshrc

**How to Solve issue**
[image]

**How to open .zhrc file**

1. open finder
2. try command + shift + G
3. search for ~/.zshrc
4. open .zshrc file and Edit then save
5. close terminal and open it again

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't delete the command to solve the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Move command `source <(ng completion script)` from `~/.zshrc` file to the end of `~/.zprofile` file.

This way, the `ng` command would be referenced correctly after zsh startup scripts load. [@starterProgrammer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76197584/3944673) is not correct as it deletes the command and doesn't solve the problem. Also, no need to reinstall the angular CLI if it is already installed.